# Javascript InnerText, setAttributes not working only on iphones

Tags: javascript

```js
let thankYouMain = document.querySelector(".thank-you-main-div");
    
    let woocommerceTYBtn = document.querySelectorAll(
      ".woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file"
    );

    //get product title
    let productTitle = document.querySelectorAll(".download-product a");

    //get product price
    let priceAmount = document.querySelectorAll(".woocommerce-Price-amount bdi");
    
    //create elements for each product item
    for (let i = 0; i < woocommerceTYBtn.length; i++) {
      let thankYouInnerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    
      thankYouInnerDiv.setAttribute("class", "thank-you-inner-div");
    
      thankYouMain.append(thankYouInnerDiv);
    
      let thankYouImg = document.createElement("img");
    
      thankYouImg.setAttribute(
        "src",
        "https://slowtravellerss.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/IMG_0169.png"
      );
    
      thankYouImg.setAttribute("width", "300px");
    
      let thankYouContent = document.createElement("div");
    
      thankYouContent.setAttribute("class", "thank-you-content");
    
      let thankYouDownloadBtn = document.createElement("a");
    
      thankYouDownloadBtn.setAttribute("class", "thank-you-dw-btn");
    
      thankYouDownloadBtn.textContent = "Download";
    
      thankYouInnerDiv.append(thankYouImg, thankYouContent, thankYouDownloadBtn);
    
      let thankYouProductTitle = document.createElement("a");
    
      thankYouProductTitle.setAttribute("class", "thank-you-pd-title");
    
      let thankYouProductDevider = document.createElement("span");
    
      thankYouProductDevider.setAttribute("class", "thank-you-pd-devider");
    
      let thankYouProductPrice = document.createElement("p");
    
      thankYouProductPrice.setAttribute("class", "thank-you-pd-price");
    
      thankYouContent.append(
        thankYouProductTitle,
        thankYouProductDevider,
        thankYouProductPrice
      );
    
      //function to set href via get and set attributes
      function settingAttr() {
        thankYouDownloadBtn.setAttribute(
          "href",
          woocommerceTYBtn[i].getAttribute("href")
        );
        thankYouProductTitle.innerText = productTitle[i].innerText;
        thankYouProductPrice.innerText = priceAmount[i].innerText;
      }
      settingAttr();
    }
```

```html
<div class="download-product">
        <a href="download.com">This is the product title</a>
        </div>
        <div class="woocommerce-Price-amount"><bdi>$99</bdi></div>
        <a href="testfile.com" class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file">Download</a>
            <div class="thank-you-main-div">   
                    
                </div>
```

I am trying to get data from one set of divs and show it in another div dynamically using getAttribute, setAttribute and innerText. The code is working fine on windows, mac and android devices. You can see the below code working just fine, But it does not work on iPhones. I tried using android and it works without any issue. This happens only on iphones. No idea how to fix this or find the issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Uhm, use className to switch the class value! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className

Answer (score -1):

This first part is to the point, but the latter section is "Meh. Take it if it makes sense." Sorry, I'm a bit of a snob. I have, uhm, "aesthetic" issues with what you're doing, but I'll separate that from the functionally-relevant issue.

**The main bits**

The main problem is that you're trying to use setAttribute for a structural, rendering-related attribute. I don't see why it'd be a "SHOULD NOT support" usage, but I'm not surprised it's a "MAY support" usage. In the following jsfiddle, I switch out your use of `<element>.setAttribute` for use of `<element>.classList.add`, and I confirm it's working as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/azpLj57f/1/ Note that the use of `<element>.setAttribute` for other attributes is retained...so far.

**The opinionated fluff**
I do hope you actually like this version of. It's going to look quite different, but I'll edit it to answer any questions you add in the comments: https://jsfiddle.net/q1my9c45/